# .NET Web Method not being called from javascript only Page

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, postman, webmethod

I have a web method in a codebhind of a .aspx page, but when I try to access it doesn't trigger the webmethod only the page. The return status is 200, the page is being called, but the method is being ignored. It doesn't matter if I use name.aspx/GetData or name.aspx/Anything, the result is 200 but the method not fired. I tested both with jquery Ajax and Postman. Get and Post attempts. 
Is there anything to alter in the web.config or any other thing.

```
$.ajax({
                        url: '/adm/clientAccess.aspx/MyMethodInexistent',
                        data: {},
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function (data) {
                           //I GET HERE even if the method doesn't exist, and if it exists, it doesn't return data.
                           alert(1);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    }
                    );
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you don't post any code, you know more about the problem than we do. How could we possibly help you? Please read the guidelines on how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, I added now.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using ?  it should be `url: '/adm/clientAccess.aspx/MyMethod',` to call the method. Try to add a breakpoint in the method to see if you are able to reach it.

Comment: Hi. It is 3.5. I am unable to debug, cause I am using Visual Studio Code, I am testing on a remote server and the pages are not compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with the below code , make sure the path to the method is correct in the `url` below. also enable page methods at the scriptmanager level if you are using one.

```
   $.ajax({
    url: '/adm/clientAccess.aspx/MyMethod',
    data: {},
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: "true",
    success: function (data) {
       console.log(data);
       //alert(1);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
}
);
```

Comment: Hi. I tried to do that, adding the scriptManager with EnablePageMethods, but the result is the same, it returns the entire page, it doesn't trigger the method, and I still can call an existent method.

Comment: <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" >
            </asp:ScriptManager>

Comment: Wow, good news, it worked with the contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8". It was a combination of everything. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Need to enable page methods using ScriptManager element:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scm" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>
```